# plt.imshow() doesn't show proper masked array(np.ma.masked_where())

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, segmentation-fault, mask

I am facing this problem while trying to plot a masked array from a segmentation mask using **plt.imshow()** and **np.ma.masked_where()**. I have used this codes previously and it worked perfectly fine. But now it's showing incomplete masks. How can I resolve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just install matplotlib version 3.1.3